# Database script encounterd "AWKDBE018E Cannot access required JDBC Driver folder" in Workload Scheduler

Tags: scheduler, ibm-cloud, workload

I create a step of database script which access to SQL Database Service in Workload Scheduler Service. When I run the process, the step encountered the error below.

**error message**

> AWKDBE018E Cannot access required JDBC Driver folder

**message information**
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGSPN_9.2.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.2/common/src_ms/awsmsawkdbe.htm?lang=en

> **AWKDBE018E Cannot access required JDBC Driver folder**
>
> **Explanation**
>   The job was not able to access a JDBC Driver folder, you might not
>   have enough permissions. 
>   **System action**
>   The operation is not performed. 
>   **Operator response**
>   Verify that you have enough permissions.

This message seems to ask me to grant the proper authority to the job user. But there is no property to specify the job user of Workload Automation Agent. I use a Workload Automation Agent provisioned by Bluemix automatically.

Could you teach me which parameters are needed ?

**Database script step information**
[image]
[image]

**JDBC driver class path info**
I checked the path by the following "ls -lR" command step's log.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to have a problem with the agent, I tried to replicate the same job type but it is not working with the same error message (even using different solutions for jdbc driver path).
If you are using the Workload Automation Agent that is created for you then you could open a support ticket to have the Workload team look at that agent.

---

Edit after having support from service team:

in the jar classpath field for a predefined workload scheduler process you have to put only the path to the directory containing jar files, without putting the jar file name to use.

So, according to current Workload Scheduler documentation, you have to use the following value:
/home/wauser/utils

By this way the database script works fine.
(screenshot added)[image]

Comment: Thank you for your support. I confirmed your suggested setting worked successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is having issues referencing the location to the JDBC class path for DB2.  Can you please double check the location for the class path for the DB2 driver?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I checked the path by "ls -lR" command step's log. I added this information in the original question. I tried  "/home/wauser/utils/db2jcc4.jar", but resulted in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Even though old, I wanted to make some quick checks.
This is tested on a 9.5 FP1 dynamic agent, part of the container delivery. The path values are the standard values for the container.

#### Try 1 - full path - SUCCESS

```
<jsdldatabase:driverPath>/opt/wa/TWS/jdbcdrivers/db2/</jsdldatabase:driverPath>
= Status Message:  Success
= Exit Status           : 0
```

#### Try 2 - relative path - FAIL

```
<jsdldatabase:driverPath>./jdbcdrivers/db2/</jsdldatabase:driverPath>
Job status : FAIL
===============================================================
AWKDBE018E Cannot access required JDBC Driver folder
===============================================================
```

#### Try3 - variable in path - FAIL

```
<jsdldatabase:driverPath>${UNISONHOME}/jdbcdrivers/db2/</jsdldatabase:driverPath>
===============================================================
AWKDBE018E Cannot access required JDBC Driver folder
===============================================================
```

#### Try4 - variable in path - FAIL

```
<jsdldatabase:driverPath>$UNISONHOME/jdbcdrivers/db2/</jsdldatabase:driverPath>
===============================================================
AWKDBE018E Cannot access required JDBC Driver folder
===============================================================
```

So put short you need an absolute path into that parameter.
BUT, you can set the path in a config file global to the agent

#### Try5 - variable in agent config -

Inside IWSDATA Home : wadata/JavaExt/cfg/DatabaseJobExecutor.properties, write the following line

```
jdbcDriversPath=/opt/wa/TWS/jdbcdrivers
```

then remove the xml element about driver from the job, so no line

```
<jsdldatabase:driverPath>/opt/wa/TWS/jdbcdrivers/db2/</jsdldatabase:driverPath>
===============================================================
= Exit Status           : 0
```

Note that in this case the jdbcdrivers/db2 is not needed. It will search for subdirectories.

Comment: Please add some tags to help viewers understand which technology you're working on. It'll also make your question easier to spot