# How can I upload a jar file for jdbc connection to workload scheduler service agent in Bluemix?

Tags: jdbc, scheduler, ibm-cloud, workload

The docs for the Workload Scheduler for Node.js says:

> "Important: Before running a database step, download and install the
>   JDBC database client driver on the agent where you want to run the
>   step. Specify the client jar file path in the JDBC jar class path."

How can I download and install the necessary JAR files to the agent? I see from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32195513/database-script-encounterd-awkdbe018e-cannot-access-required-jdbc-driver-folder/32205068#32205068) that they should be installed at `/home/wauser/utils`, but I cannot figure out how to access the agent to install.

I tried an FTP step to move the file to the agent, but it was also unsuccessful.

Comment: are you using the Workload Automation Agent that is provided in Bluemix or did you download one to your local environment?

Answer (score 0):

From your description I assume your are trying to run SQL steps on the xx_CLOUD agent.
Where is the database running and which type of database is it? is it on Bluemix or somewhere else?

Currently the best way to run SQL steps is to use a workload scheduler agent installed on a VM or a docker image, so that you can easily install the jdbc jar files.